# Postgres how to convert milliseconds to date with day light saving

Tags: postgresql, timezone, psql, dst

I have date time stored as milliseconds in postgres DB as bigint. I need to convert them to Date Time. Function to_timestamp() is not taking into consideration day light saving settings.
For example I have the following values in DB:

```
select username, created_timestamp, to_timestamp(created_timestamp/1000) from user_entity;

             username         | created_timestamp | to_timestamp
    --------------------------+-------------------+-----------------------
     user_15                  |     1567066962775 | 2019-08-29 08:22:42+00
     user_16                  |     1581145146219 | 2020-02-08 06:59:06+00
```

I would like to see the following result as a daylight saving effect:

```
user_15 | 29.08.2019, 09:22 
user_16 | 08.02.2020, 06:59
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set `timezone` to the time zone in which you want to see the strings formatted, you will get the result you desire:

```
SET timezone = 'Europe/London';
```

PostgreSQL formats `timestamp with time zone` to the current session time zone.

Comment: Does it possible to set client timezone using jdbc url parameters?

Comment: Sure, use the `options` parameter to pass `timezone`. See [the documentation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html#connection-parameters).